# Hadoop configuration object not pointing to hdfs file system

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to create small Spark program in Java. I am creating a Hadoop configuration object as show below:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration(false);
conf.addResource(new Path("/dir/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/dir/hdfs-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/dir/yarn-site.xml"));
```

When I call the following I get file system but it points to local file system and not the hdfs file system

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

I am new to Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

I usually keep the `core-site.xml` (along with the other files) in the classpath and get the configuration as follows:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem localfs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

Here is the content of my `core-site.xml`:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://{hadoop-server-addr}</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi even if I dont specify conf.set("fs.defaultFS") it is still returning me local file system object

Comment: In my case I generate a fat jar, may be in your case the conf files aren't in the classpath of your nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Add your hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml to class path. And use following code.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.newInstance(conf);
```

It will pick the configs mentioned in the xmls.

Answer (score 0):

To debug the issue better, add this line after creating a new Configuration instance. This will give you a better idea.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration(false);
conf.setQuietMode(false);
```

In most cases, defaulting to local filesystem instead of hdfs occurs when `Configuration` is not able to load resources specified by the Path strings. In such cases, the default behaviour of `Configuration` is to fail quietly and return `null` for requested key. In this case, the requested key is `fs.defaultFS` , the namenode host. `FileSystem` instance then defaults to the `file:///` scheme which is the local file system.